# C++ put function pointer into a map in one line

Tags: c++

In my project i have following functions:

```
static void test0(void)
{
    printf("%s [%d]\n", __func__, __LINE__);
}

static void test0(int a)
{
    printf("%s [%d] %d\n", __func__, __LINE__, a);
}


static std::map<std::string, void*> getAddressMap()
{
    std::map<std::string, void*> addressmap;

    void (*select1)(void) = test0;  // will match void(void)
    addressmap["test0"]=reinterpret_cast<void *>(select1);

    void (*select2)(int) = test0;   // will match void(int)
    addressmap["test0"]=reinterpret_cast<void *>(select2);
    return addressmap;
}
```

At this point you can see that in order to store each pointer in the map I need to define a special pointer and only then i can store it in the map...

Since all of these methods and stubs i am generating from a template, it would be more practical to do it using just one line. So, my question is, is there a way to do it in just one line ?

Comment: Not pretty sure as I can't test it right now, but can't you just insert your function names in your `reinterpret_cast<void *>(...);`?

Comment: @Klaus well , i can but since some of them are overriden i get missing contextual info error if i just insert it into the reinterpret_cast without mentioning the parameters...

Comment: yup got confused... I see the problem now, just use `reinterpret_cast<void *>(static_cast<void (*)(void)>(test0));` and same with int respectively.

Comment: Just a side-note: you should use `void(*)()` for your function pointers, not plain `void*`. In theory, a universal data pointer could have different alignment/size then a universal function pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting the function pointer (before casting to void*) should work just fine...

```
addressmap["test0"] = reinterpret_cast<void *>(static_cast<void(*)(void)>(test0));
addressmap["test0"] = reinterpret_cast<void *>(static_cast<void(*)(int)>(test0));
```

Comment: Note that static casts are cleaner in this situation, as your casts would also work if there are no such overloads available.

Comment: @Klaus when i static cast that, i get `invalid static_cast from type 'void (*)()' to type 'void*'` though :(

Comment: Do you have it like Robert edited it now? I meant static cast just for the inner cast

Comment: @Klaus aaah, i see now, sorry, the inner static cast worked too